# Visualforce tab panel onclick event not passing value to controller

Tags: visualforce

I got some references for Visualforce tab creation but unable to find the issue. onclick function is not passing control to controller. Any help will be appreciated.

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page id="Registration" showHeader="false" controller="SolutionLibraryTabController"  title="Solution Library" standardStylesheets="false">
    <style>
        .activeTab {background-color: #236FBD; color:white; background-image:none}
        .inactiveTab { background-color: lightgrey; color:black; background-image:none}
    </style>
    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" tabClass="activeTab"  inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab" value="{!var}" >
        <apex:tab label="Search" name="srch" id="srch" onclick="setActiveTab('srch')">
            <apex:include pageName="SolutionLibrarySearch"/>            
        </apex:tab>
        <apex:tab label="Insert" name="insrt" id="insrt" onclick="setActiveTab('insrt')">
            <apex:include pageName="SolutionLibraryInsert"/>                                       
        </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction name='setActiveTab' action='{!setActiveTab}' reRender="none">
            <apex:param id='tabname'  assignTo="{!var}" value=""/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Cotroller**

```
public class SolutionLibraryTabController {
    /*Tab var*/
    public String var{get;set;}

    public SolutionLibraryTabController(){
        var = 'srch';
    }

    public PageReference setActiveTab() {
        if(var=='srch'){
            var='insrt';
        }
        else {
            var = 'srch';
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current page? What do you mean by it is not passing control back to controller? What is your issue?

Comment: In this visualforce page there are two tab. Search tab is default. Nothing happen on click of insert tab.

Comment: Do you have `jQuery` elsewhere on the page and didn't include it here?

Comment: apex:tab itself can enable you to switch between tabs. So If all of your actionFunction code is just to switch between tabs, I suggest you to remove all of them - you are only confusing the page

Comment: @Adrian Larson - No JQuery code in page.

Comment: @Lance Shi - I already tried without apex:actionfunction and it is not working

Comment: Not working means can't you switch between tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your vf page like this. If you need to pass control to controller remove `onclick` and use `ontableave` or`ontabenter` events. Call your actionmethod inside that. I just executed below code successfully. And one more thing you don't need to pass `{!var}` as parameter with your actionmethod. Since its a controller variable bind with your vf page it will update on tab change.

Vf page:-

```
<apex:page id="Registration" showHeader="false" controller="SolutionLibraryTabController"  title="Solution Library" standardStylesheets="false">

    <style>
        .activeTab {background-color: #236FBD; color:white; background-image:none}
        .inactiveTab { background-color: lightgrey; color:black; background-image:none}
    </style>

    <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" tabClass="activeTab"  inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab" value="{!var}" >
        <apex:tab label="Search" name="srch" id="srch" ontableave="setActiveTab();" >
            <apex:include pageName="SolutionLibrarySearch"/>            
        </apex:tab>
        <apex:tab label="Insert" name="insrt" id="insrt" ontableave="setActiveTab();" >
            <apex:include pageName="SolutionLibraryInsert"/>                                       
        </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="setActiveTab" action="{!setActiveTab}" reRender="none" />
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Controller:-

```
public class SolutionLibraryTabController {
    /*Tab var*/
    public String var{get;set;}

    public SolutionLibraryTabController(){
        var = 'srch';
    }

    public PageReference setActiveTab() {
        if(var=='srch'){
            var='insrt';
        }
        else {
            var = 'srch';
        }
        System.debug('var  '+var);//Use debug to check if value is there
        return null;
    }
}
```

Check debug:-

> 12:20:39:021 USER_DEBUG [16]|DEBUG|var  insrt
>
> 12:17:28:023 USER_DEBUG [17]|DEBUG|var  srch

Comment: onclick ideally should work

Comment: Thanks Reshma. It is working for me. Now getting different problem. I am using bootstrap in my both visualforce and when I am removing then tab is working. Is there a workaround for this issue ?

Comment: @NeelKamal can you post it as a different question.

Answer (score 1):

The possible ways to make it workable are as follows:

> 1. Do not specify `switchType = "client"`, make it default be server.
> 2. Use tab panel Id and try to rerender from actionFunction.
> 3. Use selectedTab attribute of `<apex:tabPanel/>`

```
<apex:page id="Registration" showHeader="false" controller="SolutionLibraryTabController"  title="Solution Library" standardStylesheets="false">
    <style>
        .activeTab {background-color: #236FBD; color:white; background-image:none}
        .inactiveTab { background-color: lightgrey; color:black; background-image:none}
    </style>
    <apex:tabPanel tabClass="activeTab"  id="tabpanelId" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab" value="{!var}" selectedTab="{!var}">
        <apex:tab label="Search" name="srch" id="srch" onclick="setActiveTab('srch')">
            <apex:include pageName="SolutionLibrarySearch"/>            
        </apex:tab>
        <apex:tab label="Insert" name="insrt" id="insrt" onclick="setActiveTab('insrt')">
            <apex:include pageName="SolutionLibraryInsert"/>                                       
        </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabPanel>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="setActiveTab" action="{!setActiveTab}" reRender="tabpanelId,values">
            <apex:param id="tabname"  assignTo="{!var}" value=""/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
        
        <apex:outputPanel id="values">
            <apex:outputText value="{!var}" label="You have selected:" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

For more information, refer [apex:tab](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_tab.htm) and [apex:tabPanel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_tabPanel.htm)